# PgSql Insert multiple records with multiple regexp_split_to_table

Tags: postgresql, multiple-columns, bulkinsert, insert-into

I have a table with columns [FileId, FileName, FileUrl]. 
I get FileName and FileUrl as comma separated string (v_FileName, v_FileUrl) in input params of my INSERT stored proc and FileId is auto increament.
Records insert successfully for FileName if I use regexp_split_to_table single time as follows:

```
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE
    SELECT nextval('mytable_fileid_seq'),
    ,regexp_split_to_table
    ,'testurl'
   FROM regexp_split_to_table(v_FileName, E',')
```

This successfully inserts rows for all filenames in the v_FileName param and set 'testurl' for fileurl as in above test script.

My query is, is it possbile to set FileUrl as well using regexp_split_to_table for v_FileUrl param also in such single go ? I tried but it gave error "regexp_split_to_table is used more than once" kind of error. *(May be I am not using it properly.)*

Or suggest me any other way to insert records with such input params.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example of input, and what you expect to get? I'm not quite sure if you get several filenames, several urls, one of each...?

Comment: ok. Assume I have a function with 2 input params of type text as mentioned. param v_FileName may contain value : 'file1.jpeg,file2.pdf,file3.doc'. At the same time v_FileUrl may have : 'www.abc.com/file1.jpeg,www.abc.com/file2.pdf,www.file3.doc'. With this data the code should insert 3 rows in the table with respective values in respective column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `unnest` with `regexp_split_to_array`:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(
    regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c',','),
    regexp_split_to_array('1,2,3',',')
);
```

Result:

```
 unnest | unnest 
--------+--------
 a      | 1
 b      | 2
 c      | 3
```

So in your case:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (FileName, FileUrl)
SELECT *
FROM unnest(
    regexp_split_to_array(v_FileName,','),
    regexp_split_to_array(v_FileUrl,',')
);
```

(I'm assuming your FileId has a proper `default` value using the sequence).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store comma separating string in to multiple rows. You can check below code;

Comma sepearated string - "1,2,3,4,5,6"

```
create table schema_name.table_name(id int);

insert into schema_name.table_name
(
SELECT CAST(regexp_split_to_table('1,2,3,4,5,6', ',') AS INTEGER) AS id
) ;

select  * from schema_name.table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well below solution worked for me per what exactly I was expecting. Giving solution with extending MYTABLE as my actual table contains more columns. Also, it would be more helpful for others with same requirements.

Columns:

```
FileId, StoryId, FileName, FileHref, InsertDate
```

INSERT stored proc input params with sample values:

```
v_StoryId = 5678,
v_FileName = 'File_1.jpg,File_2.pdf,File_3.jpg,File_4.pdf'
v_FileHref = 'www.abc.com/File_1.jpg,www.abc.com/File_2.pdf,www.abc.com/File_3.jpg,www.abc.com/File_4.pdf'
```

The code block that works:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
(SELECT NextVal('mytable_fileid_seq')   
        ,v_StoryId
        ,FileName.regexp_split_to_table         
        ,FileHref.regexp_split_to_table
        ,LOCALTIMESTAMP
        FROM    (   select row_number() over () as idx,
                    i as regexp_split_to_table
                    from UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(v_FileName,',')) i 
                )as FileName
                JOIN (  select row_number() over () as idx,
                        i as regexp_split_to_table
                        from UNNEST(string_to_array(v_FileHref,',')) i 
                        )as FileHref
                ON FileName.idx = FileHref.idx
                );
```

Result:

```
FileId  | StoryId   | FileName  |FileHref       |InsertDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23      | 1234      |File_1.jpg |www.abc.com/File_1.jpg | 2016-12-14 12:11:54.374933
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24      | 1234      |File_2.pdf |www.abc.com/File_2.pdf | 2016-12-14 12:11:54.374933
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
25      | 1234      |File_3.jpg |www.abc.com/File_3.jpg | 2016-12-14 12:11:54.374933
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
26      | 1234      |File_4.pdf |www.abc.com/File_4.pdf | 2016-12-14 12:11:54.374933
```

However, currently it feels fishy using regexp_split_to_table() together with unnest() but as in my case, the comma separated values may not increase then 30 so the snippet should be ok. Currently I am new to pgsql, but if anyone have better/neat solution then certainly appreciated.

Thanks @[jcaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527940/jcaron) for showing a direction towards solution.